# Accessing https response object from external API in a node express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, betfair

My code currently makes a request to an external API which then responds with a JSON object. I currently log that to my console so no problems on that end. I need to reference the object externally however so I can display it on my pug page to the client.

The following external javascript file 'server2.js' is in the same location as app.js.

```
function DemoApiNgClient() {
    var FIRST_INDEX = 0;
    var DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'utf-8';
    var DEFAULT_JSON_FORMAT = '\t';

    var options = {
        hostname: 'api.betfair.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-Application': '',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-Authentication': 'emTox++='
        }
    }

    console.log("Get horse racing event id");
    // Define Horse Racing in filter object
    var jsonRequest = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"SportsAPING/v1.0/' + 'listEventTypes' + '", "params": {"filter":{}}, "id": 1}'
    var str = '';
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding(DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function (chunk) {
            // On resposne parse Json and check for errors
            response = JSON.parse(str);
            console.log('Here is our response! ' + util.inspect(response, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))

        });     
    });
    // Send Json request object
    req.write(jsonRequest, DEFAULT_ENCODING);
    req.end();

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
}
```

I have tried the exports module for nested functions however the res.on block isn't necessarily a function so it won't work doing it that way.

End goal is displaying the response object from the external API in pug on client side, and not being able to reference the object is my only sticky point, everything else works.

Comment: You have to use the `response` object inside the `res.on('end, ...)` event handler.  That's the only place it is valid and the only place you can safely use it.  So, call some function from there and pass the `response` object to that function and process it there.  This is how async development works in node.js.  It is a common point of confusion among node.js beginners and there are literally hundreds of posts about this general topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My only other thoughts are whether I could add a res.send function and have this script within my app.js so it directly sends to whatever URL I determine, e.g. 

app.post('/table'.....
    Make call to external API here..
   res.send(response)?????